# cornerstone: Recover a file after ignored

Tags: svn, ignore, cornerstone

I'm new to Cornerstone. I checked out a work copy and added some files. But there is a question mark after a file. Then I right-clicked and ignored the file, so the file is gone from Cornerstone. Now I want this file to be recovered and back to the Cornerstone even if it is still with a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

When you ignore a file, you're actually adding an 'ignore' tag to the file's parent folder; this is actually occurring in Subversion and Cornerstone is just the messenger.

To fix this in Cornerstone, right-click on the parent folder and select "Get Info". This will open the Inspector panel on the right. Switch to the "Properties" view, find and click on the ignore tag in question, and hit the delete key. Your missing file should reappear. You may need to "commit" the change to the parent folder to make this permanent.